# Генератор массивов в Kotlin?

Tags: python, kotlin

Подскажите есть ли в Kotlin генератор массивов подобно пайтону:

```
a = [i.something for i in array]
```

Comment: Именно такого в kotlin нет. Есть последовательности (sequence), с помощью которых можно делать такие вещи (но синтаксис совершенно другой). Примеры можно посмотреть здесь: https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/07/23/kotlin-sequence-tutorial/

Comment: Для данного случая можно использовать `map`: `val a = array.map { it.something }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так могу предложить

```
val intArray = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
    
val strArray = Array(intArray.size, { i -> "#${intArray[i]}" })
// [#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #0]
```